# Insert ViewControllers in UICollectionView calling lifeCycle methods - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a UICollectionView to create a Swipeable Menu like this:

[image: CollectionView]

I've chosen to use a collectionView because it's so much easier than a PageViewController to perform some tasks (since UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView).

There's one downside though, I don't know how to insert the ViewContollers inside the UICollectionViewcells and if upon scrolling the viewController's methods (such as ViewDidAppear, ViewDidDisappear) are called, I actually tried so many things but I couldn't find a way to solve this.

So summarising what I want to accomplish is: Insert ViewControllers inside CollectionViewCells so that when I scroll through the CollectionView, the lifecycle methods of VCs (ViewDidAppear, ViewDidDisappear) are called.

On StackOverFlow I've seen many topics talking about how to insert ViewControllers in cells but NEVER about calling the lifecycle methods inside them upon scrolling.

This is my CollectionView code:

```
 private let reuseIdentifier1 = "Cell1"
 private let reuseIdentifier2 = "Cell2"


class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    self.collectionView.bounces = false

    self.collectionView!.register(CollectionViewCell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier1)
    self.collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier2)

}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    switch indexPath.item {
    case 0:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier1, for: indexPath)
        return cell

    default:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier2, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}}
```

Comment: I don't know if embedding view controllers in a cell is good thing. An alternative is to use a TabBarController and hide its bottom bar. and add left and right swipe gesture to it.

Comment: Thanks,  I've seen that in that case the swipe gesture is not animated